# Postgres конкатенация

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql

DB: Postgres11
Впервые проектирую БД. Возможно ли в insert-e создать столбец, который будет конкатенировать значения других столбцов для строки или лучше писать скрипт для формирования тела запроса?

Comment: А зачем нужен столбец, собирающий значения других столбцов ? Любая информация в БД должна храниться в единственном экземпляре и не должно быть зависимостей одних столбцов от других

Comment: Конкатенировать нужно в запросе или в логике приложения. Второе предпочтительнее.

Comment: Для формирования уникального идентификатора. Если вкратце, суть такая: есть id клиента, id артикула. Хотелось бы сцеплять их для того, чтобы формировать из них primary key. Пару лет назад был консультантом по одному проекту, в котором был такой же концепт. Не берусь утверждать насколько это правильно, но тогда идея казалось удобной.

Comment: Тогда надо не париться и сделать primary key из двух полей, вот прямо `primary key(id_client, id_articul)`

Comment: @mike, но в таком случае будет два столбца primary key,  а хотелось бы получить именно один столбец, в котором данные сцеплены

Comment: @АлексейМ. , не нагуглил, как в insert конкатенировать. В select - без проблем. Может есть примеры у Вас?

Comment: @fedorov.evgeny у меня точно нет.

Comment: @fedorov.evgeny А какой смысл в сцепленном ? Если вы по нему ссылаетесь из другой таблицы то гораздо правильнее и там сделать 2 поля. тогда при необходимости вы сможете получить одно из этих полей не используя join с основной таблицей (и не прибегая к строковым функциям), что полезно. А если ссылок нет, то тогда чем он лучше обычного порядкового id ? (ну кроме того, что он строка, да еще небось в десятичном виде, которая легко читается человеком, но которая занимает лишнее место и главное значительно снижает скорость поиска)

Comment: @Mike, понял о чем Вы. Спасибо.